# Custom sort works in an unexpected way

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, stl

I am getting unexpected results in the following custom compare for sort of my vector elements.

```
int dateCompare(string d1,string d2)
{
    int rc;
    const char *d3 = d1.c_str();
    const char *d4 = d2.c_str();

    // compare years
    rc = strncmp(d3 + 6, d4 + 6, 4);
    if (rc != 0)
        return rc;

    // compare months
    rc = strncmp(d3 + 3, d4 + 3, 2);
    if (rc != 0)
        return rc;

    // compare days
    return strncmp(d3, d4, 2);
}


 vec.push_back("01/10/2015"); 
 vec.push_back("02/11/2015"); 
 vec.push_back("03/09/2015"); 
 sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), dateCompare);

Input:
01/10/2015
02/11/2015
03/09/2015

Output:
03/09/2015
02/11/2015
01/10/2015
```

I know there are other better ways to compare the date and change the structure itself of the elements etc. But more than that, i am trying to figure out why there is indiscrepancy in the way the `std::sort` function works i.e. why it swaps irrespective of the comparator returns `true` or `false`

`dateCompare()` is called twice for these 3 elements.

**First time =>** `dateCompare("02/11/2015","01/10/2015")` is called and during evaluation of `strcmp(11,10)` , returns **true** and hence there is swap. So the vec changed from

```
{"01/10/2015","02/11/2015","03/09/2015"} to  {"02/11/2015","01/10/2015","03/09/2015"}
```

**Second time ->** `dateCompare("03/09/2015","02/11/2015")` is called and during evaluation of `strcmp(09,11)` , returns **false** *and a swap was not expected but still it swapped*. So the vec changes from

```
{"02/11/2015","01/10/2015","03/09/2015"} to {"03/09/2015","01/10/2015","02/11/2015"}
```

So i changed the input(`03/09/2015` changed to `03/12/2015`) so that the second compare returns true(instead of false), but it still swaps and the result :

```
01/10/2015
02/11/2015
03/12/2015


03/12/2015
02/11/2015
01/10/2015
```

It looks like it swaps no matter the return is `true` or `false`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::sort` expects the comparator to return a boolean - true if the first argument should precede the second argument in the sort order, false otherwise. A comparator that, like yours, returns -1, 0 or 1 (for less-than, equal, greater-than) is not suitable for `std::sort`; it violates the requirements of a strict weak ordering. Your program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: In my example, it either returns 1 or -1. Do 1 or -1 are not converted to boolean true or false and i should strictly change 1 and -1 to return true or false?

Comment: Both 1 and -1 are `true` in boolean context (any non-zero integer is taken a `true`, zero as `false`). So your comparator says, for any two dates `d1` and `d2`, that `d1` should precede `d2` and at the same time `d2` should precede `d1` - thus violating the requirement that a strict weak ordering should be asymmetric (if `x < y`, then `!(y < x)`)